# Disable class instance methods

Tags: python

How can I quickly disable all methods in a class instance based on a condition? My naive solution is to override using the `__getattr__` but this is not called when the function name exists already.

```
class my():
    def method1(self):
        print 'method1'
    def method2(self):
        print 'method2'
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print 'Fetching '+str(name)
        if self.isValid():
            return getattr(self, name)
    def isValid(self):
        return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m=my()
    m.method1()
```

Comment: Why?  What's the use case for this?  Can you provide some context in which you'd need to "disable" access?  What access are you disabling?  Just method functions?  Why not use `if` statements?  Is this an example of the **State** design pattern?

Comment: The question implies the search for a single point / post hoc solution, and for this the `__getaddr__` approach seems to be the only way, with the caveat stressed in Alex' answer: `every` single attribute access will suffer the overhead.  Have you considered a decorator which tests the isValid status and return directly or passes on to the orginal method instead?  This approach would require a "change" to all (most) methods, but would also provide more control over the process and only affect methods not every single attribute.  In a sense, getting closer to what S Lott suggests.

Comment: As mjv said, I needed a generalised mechanism to prevent the user from accessing methods when the class is in a specific state i.e. raising a value error when user tried to read a customer's name while the customer's class has not yet loaded the data from the db. I did not wanted to raise it on each individual method. As a beginner Python programmer, I thought there might be a better way to do all these checks from a centralised place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of what you want to do is actually to override `__getattribute__`, which is going to be called for **every** attribute access.  Besides it being very slow, take care: by definition of **every**, that includes e.g. the call to `self.isValid` within `__getattribute__`'s own body, so you'll have to use some circuitous route to access that attribute (`type(self).isValid(self)` should work, for example, as it gets the attribute from the class, not from the instance).

This points to a horrible terminological confusion: this is **not** disabling "method from a class", but from an **instance**, and in particular has nothing to do with `classmethods`.  If you do want to work in a similar way on a class basis, rather than an instance basis, you'll need to make a custom metaclass and override `__getattribute__` **on the metaclass** (that's the one that's called when you access attributes **on the class** -- as you're asking in your title and text -- rather than **on the instance** -- as you in fact appear to be doing, which is by far the more normal and usual case).

**Edit**: a completely different approach might be to use a peculiarly Pythonic pathway to implementing the `State` design pattern: class-switching.  E.g.:

```
class _NotValid(object):
  def isValid(self):
    return False
  def setValid(self, yesno):
    if yesno:
      self.__class__ = TheGoodOne

class TheGoodOne(object):
  def isValid(self):
    return True
  def setValid(self, yesno):
    if not yesno:
      self.__class__ = _NotValid
  # write all other methods here
```

As long as you can call `setValid` appropriately, so that the object's `__class__` is switched appropriately, this is very fast and simple -- essentially, the object's `__class__` is where all the object's methods are found, so by switching it you switch, en masse, the set of methods that exist on the object at a given time.  However, this does not work if you absolutely insist that validity checking must be performed "just in time", i.e. at the very instant the object's method is being looked up.

An intermediate approach between this and the `__getattribute__` one would be to introduce an extra level of indirection (which is popularly held to be the solution to all problems;-), along the lines of:

```
class _Valid(object):
  def __init__(self, actualobject):
    self._actualobject = actualobject
  # all actual methods go here
  # keeping state in self._actualobject

class Wrapit(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._themethods = _Valid(self)
  def isValid(self):
    # whatever logic you want
    # (DON'T call other self. methods!-)
    return False
  def __getattr__(self, n):
    if self.isValid():
      return getattr(self._themethods, n)
    raise AttributeError(n)
```

This is more idiomatic than `__getattribute__` because it relies on the fact that `__getattr__` is only called for attributes that aren't found in other ways -- so the object can hold normal state (data) in its `__dict__`, and that will be accessed without any big overhead; only method calls pay the extra overhead of indiretion.  The `_Valid` class instances can keep some or all state in their respective `self._actualobject`, if any of the state needs to stay accessible on invalid objects (so that the invalid state disable methods, but not data attributes access; it's not clear from your Q if that's needed, but it's a free extra possibility offered by this approach).  This idiom is less error-prone than `__getattribute__`, since state can be accessed more directly in the methods (without triggering validity checks).

As presented, the solution creates a circular reference loop, which may impose a bit of overhead in terms of garbage collection.  If that's a problem in your application, use the [weakref](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html?highlight=weakref#module-weakref) module from the standard Python library, of course -- that module is generally the simplest way to remove circular loops of references, if and when they're a problem.
(E.g., make the `_actualobject` attribute of `_Valid` class instances a *weak* reference to the object that holds that instance as its `_themethods` attribute).

Comment: Point taken, it is the instance I am interested!

Comment: Finding self.isValid() without triggering __getattribute__ in an instance is quite tricky!

Comment: What's wrong with the specific expression I suggest in the answer above, `type(self).isValid(self)`?  Of course, the `isValid` method itself must take care to *not* access attributes on `self` as such (e.g., by looking into `self.__dict__` instead). If you insist on this general approach, it's feasible, though full of potential traps. Otherwise, you can choose a less facile approach, e.g. the ones suggested in comments to your Q or others yet (let me edit my A to suggest one).

Comment: Nothing wrong, it is just me who is getting the grips of working in Python. I believed type(self).isValid(self) is a static method and could not see how it would be associated with the instance.